I can't play multiple sounds on iOS due to restrictions. Work-arounds for a game?
I am creating a JavaScript game that needs sound to make it engaging, even without client interaction. However, on iOS, there are heavy restrictions in place to prevent potential misuse of sounds, videos, etc., which I completely understand.
In my case, I have one button to start the game. There are a few other buttons, but none of which could be used for the sounds I want to play.
Knowing the restrictions, are there any other possible work-arounds for this besides buttons/clicks?
I have done some research on SO, Reddit and ChatGPT, and so far nothing fits this type of situation (an application that needs audio without more than 1-2 document clicks).
One thing I have tried is using the first button (the game start button) to play multiple clips. However, this only played one of them.
Are there any possible or ideal solutions? My guess is no, but it doesn't hurt to have extra opinions.
Thanks in advance.

One of the possible solutions would be to do audio mixing yourself.
For example, using the Web Audio API
It may seem overkill at first glance. But given that you are developing a game, and games usually need to deal with lots of sounds, it may prove useful as soon as your game audio starts getting more and more complicated.
One simple example to give a case proving its usefulness:
Let's say you have a sound coin_collected.ogg. You need to play it every time the user grabs a coin. If the user grabs 10 coins with a slight delay each, the sound should be played correspondingly.
But without mixing it yourself (or using other dirty hacks), it will be extremely difficult to play the same sound file until the previous play finished (not only on iOS, but also valid for web in general)
